# Transpose vertical input data to horizontal output in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to transpose rows to columns in Oracle. I've the data in this format:

```
Apple Orange Mango Banana
15    20     12    67
```

The required result is:

```
Fruit      Number
Apple      15
Orange     20
Mango      12
Banana     67
```

I used `Union` to get this result but this is not the generic one.

```
SELECT ‘Apple’ AS Fruit, Apple AS Number FROM fruits_tbl UNION
SELECT ‘Orange’, Orange FROM fruits_tbl UNION
SELECT ‘Mango’, Mango FROM fruits_tbl UNION
SELECT ‘Banana’, Banana FROM fruits_tbl;
```

I want standard procedure to get the output as suggested.

Update: Figured out Pivot is the correct approach!

Comment: Look for `unpivot`.  Also, explain what you mean by "not the generic one".

Comment: It is always good to mention the Oracle version to get an appropriate answer. For example, in your case UNPIVOT is possible on 11g and up.

Comment: Anyway, both `UNPIVOT`-based  and `UNION`-based solutions would need to specify the column names in the query. So aren't that "generic" at all. If you don't know your column names in advance, maybe you should start looking at some dynamic-SQL based solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle 11g (`tab` is your table name):

```
select * from tab 
UNPIVOT (num for fruit in (apple as 'apple', orange as 'orange', mango as 'mango', banana as 'banana'));
```

Oracle 10g:

```
with col_names as (
select 'apple' fruit from dual
union all select 'orange' from dual
union all select 'mango' from dual
union all select 'banana' from dual
)
select c.fruit, 
       case c.fruit       
          when  'apple' then t.apple          
          when  'orange' then t.orange          
          when  'mango' then t.mango          
          when  'banana' then t.banana          
       end as num
from tab t
cross join col_names c;
```